# How we can create employee pay cheques using qbfc?

Tags: quickbooks, qbfc

I am using below code snippet to create cheques for employees using qbfc :

```
ICheckAdd chkAddQuery = requestMsgSet.AppendCheckAddRq();
chkAddQuery.AccountRef.FullName.SetValue("1001 - Bank (Test Account)");
chkAddQuery.IsToBePrinted.SetValue(true);
chkAddQuery.TxnDate.SetValue(DateTime.Now);
chkAddQuery.PayeeEntityRef.FullName.SetValue("Test Employee");
IExpenseLineAdd expAdd =  chkAddQuery.ExpenseLineAddList.Append();
expAdd.AccountRef.FullName.SetValue("1001 - Bank (Test Account)");
expAdd.Amount.SetValue(1500.00);
```

But somehow these are coming under Non-Payroll transactions and not under Pay Cheques in quickbooks, so need help in how we can can create employee pay cheques in quickbooks ?

Comment: @William Lorfing can u provide some help here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After following up with William on Intuit Developer Network i found that qbfc cannot be used to generate employee pay checks

https://help.developer.intuit.com/s/question/0D50f00004sugPACAY/how-we-can-create-employee-pay-cheques-using-qbfc